# I am trying to add a custiom property to an add on but it shows me an error

Tags: scripting, add-on, properties

I am following this video
https://youtu.be/XqX5wh4YeRw?t=2451
i have done everything the same way but it does not seem to work

here is my code

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from bpy.props import *


class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.my_operator"
    bl_label = "MyOperator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    
    
    #create properties
    noise_scale : bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = "Noise Scale",
        discrription = "the Scale of the noise",
        default =1.0,
        min = 0.0,
        max = 2.0
        )
```

and it shows me this error.
'MyOperator' object has no attribute 'noise_scale'

Comment: Quite likely the property fails to register because it has no idea what `discrription`  is. (_Most likely you are alerted to this error when trying to register the operator class_) Coding is about attention to detail.  Recommend for blender coding questions here, adding minimal, but runable, code to your question _eg_ the register code for above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spelling Error**

Quite likely the property fails to register because it has no idea what `discrription`  is. (*Most likely you are alerted to this error when trying to register the operator class*) Coding is about attention to detail.  Recommend for blender coding questions here, adding minimal, but runable, code to your question *eg* the register code for above.

Sure enough, tacking `bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)` to the question code, and checking system console

```
TypeError: 'discrription' is an invalid keyword argument for FloatProperty()
ValueError: bpy_struct "OBJECT_OT_my_operator" registration error: noise_scale could not register
```

any attempt to use `noise_scale` with this operator will lead to error as mentioned in question.

Use `description` instead and will register as intended.

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.my_operator(
my_operator()
bpy.ops.object.my_operator(noise_scale=1)
Tooltip
```